# How can I get count of occurrences from Master instance of appointment EWS?

Tags: java, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, outlook-restapi

I want to print count of total occurrences which is present in master instance of recurring appointment. While I am using

```
appointment.getRecurrence().getNumberOfOccurrences()
```

it returns null value.
How can i get that?

Comment: What about appointments with no end date?

Comment: With appointment.getRecurrence().hasEnd() we can check appointment has end date or not.

Answer (score 0):

Id do this in PHP (a little different syntax)

```
$item->getRecurrence()->getNumberedRecurrence() ? $item->getRecurrence()->getNumberedRecurrence()->getNumberOfOccurrences()+1 : 9999;
```

Hopefully there are not more than 9999 occurrences